# Have Multiple UIImageView's From 1 UIImageViews

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiimageview

I have declared 1 UIImageView in my code. Is there a way to get multiple out of it? Say for example I have an imageView called red and position that on the screen. Is there a way to have multiple of red on the screen at the one time?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One image view is one image view.

If you want more than one, declare more than one.

If you have many similar image views, consider creating one array of many image views instead of a separate property for each one.

If you have all of the image views in a storyboard or .xib file, you can use an *outlet collection* instead of an outlet to store them.